# MPMoviePlayer fullscreen playback orientation change

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer, orientation-changes

I am developing an ios application with viewcontroller which has two subviews A) mpmoviecontroller and B) pageviewcontroller. if the player is not in full screen mode and I change orientation subviews alignment is ok (I handle orientation change and make new CGRects for subviews). When I switch my video mode to full screen, rotate to landscape and zoom out,  my pageviewcontrollers view is gone out of the screen. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    [self.view addSubview: self.streamPlayer.view];
    [self.streamPlayer prepareToPlay];  
     NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8"];
    [self.streamPlayer setContentURL:streamURL];
    [self.streamPlayer play];

    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard          instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];

    [self setFramesForPotrait];

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [self setFramesForPotrait];
        NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
        NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
            }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [self setFramesForLandscapeMode];
//        self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.pageViewContainterRect;
        NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
        NSLog(@"%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
    }
}

-(void)setFramesForPotrait
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    _videoFrameRect  = CGRectMake(0,_BAR_HEIGHT, frame.size.width,_VIDEO_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT);
    _pageViewContainterRect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, _BAR_HEIGHT + _VIDEO_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT, frame.size.width, frame.size.height-_BAR_HEIGHT-_VIDEO_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT);

    [self.pageViewController.view setFrame :self.pageViewContainterRect ];
    [self.streamPlayer.view setFrame: _videoFrameRect];
}

-(void)setFramesForLandscaeMode
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    _videoFrameRect = CGRectMake(0,_BAR_HEIGHT, frame.size.height/2,frame.size.width-_BAR_HEIGHT);
    _pageViewContainterRect = CGRectMake(frame.size.height/2, _BAR_HEIGHT, frame.size.height/2,frame.size.width-_BAR_HEIGHT);

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.pageViewContainterRect;
    [self.streamPlayer.view setFrame: _videoFrameRect];
}
```